# After how many iterations will an integer circle back to 0 in Python?

Tags: python

If this question is completely garbage I apologize because I am new to CS and haven't understood at how programming languages (Python specifically) work.

I was reading about how in a standard two-byte representation of a number, if one was to increment 65,536 times, the integer would wrap back to one. Would this case occur in Python, and if so at what number would this occur?

Edit: I read a little bit further into this and it seems that after an increment, programming languages seem to redefine the value. Would this prevent this from occur

Comment: Language-specific questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Fefnir, since this is about programming, one way to gain and verify knowledge is by programming. `for i in range(65537): print("wrong") if i >= i + 1 else None;`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about python, but let me make it more general. Integers are represented in three major ways in modern computers:

1. Unsigned integers of a fixed number of bits.
2. Signed integers of a fixed number of bits.
3. Bignums, also known by various other names such as multiple precision integers.

The first two exhibit the wrap-around behavior. The third doesn't.

Python uses three different representations for integers:

1. Small integers are stored as "constants".
2. Integers which fit into a signed machine word (*plain integers*) are stored as such.
3. Larger integers (*long integers*) are stored as bignums.

This is described in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html).

Plain integers are automatically promoted to long integers if need be. Therefore the wrapping around behavior does not happen.

On a 64-bit system, $2^{63}-1$ is the largest plain integer:

```
>>> (2**62-1)*2+1
9223372036854775807
>>> 2**63
9223372036854775808L
```

Note the suffix `L`, which indicates a long integer.

Comment: This answer is correct for Python 2, but not for more recent versions, which have eliminated the distinction between `int` and `long` on the surface.